# Adding up values from a column that have the same value in another column

Tags: java, list, csv, arraylist

I'm trying to add the values in the 3rd column in the list that have the same values in column 2. For example,[2, 20003, 4] [2, 20003, 7] would return [2,20003,11], because they share 20003 in the middle column.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("file"), ',', '"', 1);
    List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll();
    for(String[] row : allRows)
    {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
 }
```

Sample output (gets output in 3 columns)
    [1, 10002, 4]
    [1, 10004, 6]
    [1, 10008, 2]
    [1, 10010, 3]
    [1, 10010, 3]
    [2, 10007, 10]
    [2, 20003, 4]
    [2, 20003, 7]
    [2, 30019, 1]
    [2, 30020, 9]

Comment: What happens if values are [1, 20003, 4] [2, 20003, 7]. You only said column 2 had to match, so what's the result going to be for column 1 using this input? --- And what have you tried so far to implement this?

Comment: Column 1 does not matter, I could even try to make a new 2D array with only columns 2 and 3. I tried to loop through it and add the number in column 3 to a new list if the number in column 2 matched, but I wasn't sure if that was the way to go.

Comment: But your question stated that you wanted [2,20003,11] as the result. That is not consistent with what you just said. This means your requirements are not well defined, and we can't help you.

Comment: Telling me I need to be consistent and have better definition of my requirements is a great way to help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This replaces the third element with the sum, creating repeated items if the same first and second element appear more than once:

```
Map<String, Integer> map
                = allRows.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[1], 
                           Collectors.summingInt(a -> Integer.valueOf(a[2]))));
List<String[]> out
                = allRows.stream()
                .map(a -> new String[]{a[0], a[1], map.get(a[1]).toString()})
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

replace the last statement with this to eliminate repeats.

```
out
            = allRows.stream()
            .map(a -> new String[]{a[0], a[1], map.get(a[1]).toString()})
            .map(a -> Arrays.toString(a))
            .distinct()
            .map(s -> s.substring(1, s.length()-1).split(","))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```